# reCaptcha verification fails with uncaught promise error

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, grecaptcha

I have encountered a problem when trying to implement reCAPTCHA v3 onto a website to prevent spam emails.

The problem I currently have is that the reCAPTCHA gives me an error that loos like this:

> Uncaught (in promise) Ogiltigt åtgärdsnamn. Namnet får endast
> innehålla bokstäverna A–Za–z eller _. Ta inte med användarspecifik
> information.

Since I'm in Sweden the error code for some reason is not in English but a rough translation makes the error something like this:

> Uncaught (in promise) Invalid action name. The name may only contain
> the letters A–Za–z or _. Do not include user-specific information.

At recaptcha_sv.js:361 and at contact.html:1

I believe it has something to do with the email using a "@" symbol as well as a ".", example "this@gmail.com", or that the name uses a space or something like this. I have googled for hours but just cant simply find my answers or the root for the problem.

To give some more context to the problem I will show the code but not the keys for the recaptcha.

contact.html

```
<body>
        <!-- Formuläret för att skicka ett E-Mail via sidan -->
        <div class="contact-container" id="contact">
            <div class="contact">
                <h1>Kontakta oss här!</h1>
                <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="contact-form" id="contact-form">
                    <input type="hidden" value="recaptchaResponse" id="recaptchaResponse">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Namn" required>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>  
                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telefonnummer" required>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="reg" id="reg" placeholder="Regnummer" required>
                    <textarea name="msg" id="msg" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Medelande" required></textarea>

                    <button type="submit" value="Skicka Mail">Skicka Mail</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=my-own-site-key"></script>
<script src="/js/init.js"></script>
</html>
```

The init.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    "use strict";
    const form = document.querySelector(".contact-form")
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        let fields = document.querySelectorAll(".contact-form .form-control")
        let valid = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
            if(fields[i].value === ""){
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        if (valid){
            grecaptcha.ready(function(){
                grecaptcha
                    .execute("my-own-site-key", {
                        action: "contact-form"
                    })
                    .then(function(token){

                        let recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById("recaptchaResponse")
                        recaptchaResponse.value = token
                        
                        fetch("/sendmail.php", {
                            method: "POST",
                            body: new FormData(form),
                        })
                        .then((response) => response.text())
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log(response)
                        })
                    })
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Lastly the sendmail.php

```
<?php

    function isValid(){
        if(
            $_POST["name"] != "" &&
            $_POST["tel"] != "" &&
            $_POST["email"] != "" &&
            $_POST["msg"] != "" &&
            $_POST["reg"] != ""
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Declare variables
    $success_output = '';
    $error_output = '';

    if (isValid()){
        $recaptcha_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"; // URL to the reCAPTCHA servers
        $recaptcha_secret = "my-little-secret-key" // reCAPTCHA secret key
        $recaptcha_response = $_POST["recaptchaResponse"]; // reCAPTCHA response from the servers, added to form during runtime
        $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url."?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$recaptcha_response); // send request to reCAPTCHA servers
        $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha); // decode the response
        if($recaptcha->success == true && $recaptcha->score >= 0.5 && $recaptcha->action == "contact-form"){
            // Send the email

            $Name = $_POST["name"];
            $Tel = $_POST["tel"];
            $MailFrom = $_POST["email"];
            $Message = UTF8_decode($_POST["msg"]);
            $Reg = $_POST["reg"];

            $MailTo  = "secret@mail.se";
            $Subject = "".$Name." | Thissite.se";

            $Headers = array(
                'From'         => $MailTo,
                'Reply-To'     => $MailTo,
                'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
                'Content-type' => 'text/html',
                'charset'      => 'UTF-8',
                'X-Mailer'     => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
            );

            $Msg = 'Namn: ' . $Name . '<br />Telefonnummer: ' . $Tel . '<br />E-mail: ' . $MailFrom . '<br />Regnummer: ' . $Reg . '<br /><br />Meddelande: ' . wordwrap($Message, 50);

            $test = mail($MailTo, $Subject, $Msg, $Headers);
            
            if ($test === true) {
                $success_output = "message was sent successfully!";
                header("Location: redirect.html");
            } else {
                $error_output = "mail error";
                echo "Meddelandet kunde inte skickas, vänligen kontakta oss på följande mail. (axel@brannhult.se)";
            }

        } else {
            // reCAPTCHA failed, dont send mail
            $error_output = "probably a robot";
            echo "Vi tror att du är en robot, är du inte en robot så vänligen kontakta oss på följande mail. (axel@brannhult.se) "
        }
    }

    // Output error or success message
    $output = [
        'error' => $error_output,
        'success' => $success_output
    ];

    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: `believe it has something to do with the email using a "@" symbol `...why? The email address is not involved in the captcha verification process.

Comment: https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/394 explains what you've done wrong (this was the first result when I [googled the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+(in+promise)+Invalid+action+name.+The+name+may+only+contain+the+letters+A%E2%80%93Za%E2%80%93z+or+_). I'm not sure what you were searching for in your searches?)

Comment: @ADyson, well to be honest I don't really understand js that much, but since the error that is given is something of the line A-Za-z and _, this makes me think it got something to do with some regex involved, im not that experienced in regex :(

Comment: Well that's just a random assumption. If you think about it logically...the error was generated from the recaptcha internal code (as per the stack trace). Recaptcha only looks at the captcha data...it doesn't use or care what else is in your form. It is not sending the rest of the form data to google, or using it to issue a verification token. It only cares what the user entered in the captcha itself

Comment: `it got something to do with some regex involved`...that's a reasonable assumption. But  
 - as per the google results - the problem is your data action value, which _is_ something that recatpcha is interested in. Did you try searching google for the error message text?